# Passing parameters to a COM interface

Tags: c#, com

I am trying to write a small c# application to test a COM interface (also written in c#). The interface contains a method which accepts a single string as a parameter.

I've included a couple code samples below. I use the following to perform the invocation:

```
public class CreateObject
{
    private Type comType;
    public object comObject;

    public CreateObject(string ProgID)
    {
        comType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(ProgID);
        comObject = Activator.CreateInstance(comType);
    }
    public void Execute(string Method, params object[] Parameters)
    {
        comType.InvokeMember(Method, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, comObject, Parameters);
    }
}
```

Which I then execute using:

```
String sParam = "test";
CreateObject obj = new CreateObject("Namespace.Class");          
obj.Execute("Method", sParam );
```

Inside the COM, interface looks like this:

```
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual), Guid("xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx")]
public interface Interface
{
    void Method(String sParam);
}
```

Simplified implementation of Method(String):

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), Guid("xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx"), ProgId("Namespace.Class")]
public class Class: Interface
{
    public void Method(String sParam)
    {
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(sParam);
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("result.xml");

        *** other code used to create the xml ***
    }
}
```

Even though there are no errors returned, the COM doesn't actually seem to execute. However when I take out the string parameter from both the test app and the COM, I do get the correct output (the COM interface creates an XML file on disc). Can anyone see a fault in my use of the parameter?

Comment: I assume the intended client won't actually be in c#.

Comment: No, there will be several clients, none of them in c#.

Comment: Perhaps we could see the implementation source for Method(String) used in this case?

Comment: David, I've edited the question to include the implementation code.

Comment: Is sParam supposed to be a URL or raw XML text?

Comment: Hmm. Well, unfortunately, I don't see anything obvious that explains the peculiar behavior you're seeing. About the only thing I could think of would be some exception tossed loading your XML string, but if there's no handlers in the code it would surely error out. I'm assuming there are no exception handlers around LoadXmL(..) (since the code you posted was noted as "simplified").

Comment: The simple explanation is that everything works just fine.  You just can't find the file back.  *Never* specify file paths that depend on the client code to set the current working directory correctly.

Comment: @Hans, I believe the OP has stated that sParam is not a file path...? Has stated pretty plainly the file is created in one version, not in another...not seeing how this is a file path issue?

Comment: Clearly "result.xml" is not a full path specification.

Comment: I've tried changing the result.xml to "C:/result.xml", but still nothing gets outputted, so I think there's no issue in the path. Like David said, there are no exception handlers and yet the client executes without any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that class libraries don't use app.config, which means my COM had no access to any of its settings (connection strings, etc.) and threw errors I couldn't see until I returned them as part of the try/catch.

So the answer is that use of parameters in this case was correct.